# Dynamic TabView primefaces, tab rendered attribute doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs, tabview, conditional-rendering

i have a "problem" with a tab component for tabView from Primefaces.
I did a tabView with dynamic  tabs based on a array.

But some tabs can't be rendered, based on a boolean attribute of the object from that array .

I tried rendered="true" or "false" but nothing happens (on tab).
I use rendered="#{_item.show}" i tried use disabled feature  and works fine, but is not my need.

Someone have an idea to how to solve this issue?

check my code:

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" value="#{myBean.list}" var="_item"  orientation="left" style="height:800px!important;" >

        <p:tab title="#{_item}" rendered="#{_item.show}" >
```

Comment: well that's weird. what happened for me is that the tab item is still rendered but its corresponding content wasn't. smells like a bug to me.

Comment: for me too, the css trick from Geinmachi worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `disabled` attribute to your `<p:tab>` and use this style for hiding tab:

```
<style>
    #tabs li.ui-state-disabled {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Value after `#` is your `<p:tabView>` clientId, so if it is in a naming container like `<h:form id="myForm">` then just change your selector to `#myForm\:tabs`.

`rendered="false"` works but it doesn't render content of the tab, not the tab itself.

Comment: I did this and worked well... 
Use css to solve this was my last option.
But thanks for the help