# primefaces accordionpanel tab render

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i'm using primefaces 5.2 .
i want to use an accordionpanel with tabs dynamically rendered.
my xhtml code :

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{rechercheBean.structures}" dynamic="true" cache="false" var ="structure">
<p:tab title="#{structure.nomStructure} #{structure.existe?'existe':'n existe pas'}" rendered="#{structure.existe}" >
</p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

the 'existe' value is stored in a boolean, my problem is that it seemed to be never used in the rendered attribute.
I 've got this result.
[tab rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daqe1.png)
I tried to write it the directly with the same result: the tab is always rendered.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rendered` behaves the same [like in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739961/dynamic-tabview-primefaces-tab-rendered-attribute-doesnt-work/) `p:tabView`, it doesn't render the content of the tab, but it renders the tab itself. In your case this style hides not rendered/disabled tabs (you can omit what's after `,` but this hides content of first tab in case it is disabled).

```
<style>
    #myPanel > h3.ui-state-disabled, #myPanel > div.ui-accordion-content {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

`p:accordionPanel` with `id` and `p:tab` with `disabled` attribute:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="myPanel" value="#{rechercheBean.structures}" dynamic="true" cache="false" var ="structure">
    <p:tab title="#{structure.nomStructure} #{structure.existe?'existe':'n existe pas'}" rendered="#{structure.existe}" disabled="#{!structure.existe}" />
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: ok i just tryed thisand the result looks good even if it 's not exactly what i wanted .